# How to list drivers/kernel modules affected by SecureBoot?

Tags: secure-boot

Is there a way to properly list the drivers or kernel modules that are affected by enabling SecureBoot on my machine?

On my machine, I have an NVIDIA video card and I have installed its binary drivers through the PPA.

I have enrolled my own machine owner's key (MOK) and have signed some of the relevant kernel modules. That seems to work, but it's all just guess work: I just typed `modinfo -n nvidia` and then used tab-completion to show the kernel modules with names starting with "nvidia". But how do I know I have been thorough and have not missed anything?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this. EFI binaries can be signed with `sbsign` and verified with `sbverify`. Kernel modules, OTOH, are signed with `sign-file`, which is part of the kernel source tree, and I don't see any obvious verification tool in the directory that holds `sign-file`. The closest I can think of to doing what you want is to enable Secure Boot and then try loading the kernel module with `modprobe` and then see if it's loaded with `lsmod`. If the module loads, then either it's signed or the kernel is not honoring Secure Boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All kernel modules that are signed will have `~Module signature appended~\n` appended to the end of the file. ([Source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/scripts/sign-file.c#L390)) To find out if there are any unsigned kernel modules, you can simply search for all `*.ko` files that don't have the magic string.

For example:

```bash
find /lib/modules -name '*.ko' -exec grep -FL '~Module signature appended~' {} \+
```